# Cross-correlation with Spearman's method

Tags: cross-correlation

I should investigate the lead-lag relationship among 2 sets of data, annual incidence of a disease and annual average data of an environmental factor for 13 consecutive years. Both sets are not normally distributed and therefore, correlation should be assessed by Spearman's correlation. But "cross-correlation analysis" in SPSS 16, checks correlation in lags by Pearson's method. SPSS does not have any option to choose the method for cross-correlation. what can I do to obtain Spearman's rho for lags?

Comment: "*Both sets are not normally distributed and therefore, correlation should be assessed by Spearman's correlation*" -- (i) why not Pearson, exactly? Where does it rely on normality? (ii) If you can't use Pearson, why Spearman, specifically? ... as for computing Spearman, why not rank your data, and then compute Pearson?

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to Transform > Rank Cases.
2. Put your two variables into the "Variables" panel.
3. Click "Rank Types" to select your preferred type of rank (the default "Rank" is fine)
4. Click "Ties" to select how you'd like SPSS to deal with ties. Again, the default "mean" is good.
5. Click "OK" and you'll get two new variables, they are the ranks of the original variable.
6. Now run Cross-correlation with Pearson's correlation on them, the ranked nature of the new variable would give you a result approximate to Spearman's correlation, which can be treated as Pearson's correlation of the ranks.

---

**Q:** Now, is there any way that I show the relationships of two variables regarding the lag with the best "R" in the form of a scatter-plot?

**A:** Yes, once you have decided a certain lag is of interest (you can find that out from the cross-correlation graphical or tabular output) and would like to show its relationship with the other variable, you can create a lagged version for plotting:

1. Transform > Compute (remember to rank your data by your time variable in ascending order first)
2. Name your new variable
3. Assume the variable you'd like to lag is called V1. Then in the formula box, type:

> lag(v1, 25)
>
> Click OK and you should see the new variable made.
>
> Proceed to make a scatter plot.
>
> Notice that, the lagged one is now actually temporally earlier than its counterpart. So, if you suspect, for example, ambient temperature leads to increased bacterial growth, you should actually lag the temperature, not bacterial growth. Alternately, you can sort your data in reversed chronological order and lag bacterial growth. Either way, apply careful judgment.

Comment: Thanks Penguin_Knight, it works very well. Now, is there any way that I show the relationships of two variables regarding the lag with the best "R" in the form of a scatter-plot?

Comment: Thanks for useful guidance. I found that the latter, i.e. making scatter-plot of lagged data is also possible through: Transform > Create Time series > Lag function   and then using scatter-plot for lagged data